# How to disable Wi-Fi and bluetooth using Apple Configurator?

Tags: ipad, wifi, bluetooth, apple-configurator

How do I **disable** Wi-Fi and bluetooth on my supervised devices using Apple Configurator?  I see options for deploying SSID setup uniformly but not the ability to disable.

We're attempting to use iPads with pre-loaded references in the classroom so we don't want the student to be able to get onto the internet or connect to any bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to disable either Wifi or Bluetooth using Apple Configurator profiles. Configurator has gotten much better over the past few years limiting various activities in academic environments, but it does not allow restrictions on a number of things that they deem important, like network & device connectivity.

Other activities, like installed new iOS updates, are also cannot be locked down. This bit us hard when 8.1 was introduced, as a number of our 1:1 students with managed iPads updated to 8.1 Several of the apps they need for their schoolwork needed updates as well and crashed, but because we restrict the App Store, we had to do a mass update with Configurator over the course of a day.